# Using random string as a token instead of JWT for authentication

Tags: authentication, token, microservices

Considering that for tokens I use randomly generated unique strings (not JWT), what the authentication flow should look like in microservice architecture?

What I've come up with so far is the following:

1. when a user logs in, the backend app sends the provided username/pass to my Authentication microservice
2. Auth. microservice verifies username/pass, generates token, saves it in its Users db (+associates the token with the current user). Then it returns the token to backend app.
3. Backend app creates a session (stores it in some in-memory db), saves this token in session, and responds to browser with a cookie.
4. On every subsequent request user sends cookie > backend app retrieves token from session data > sends it to Auth. microservice which verifies token and grants access.

Is this a solid authentication flow or am I missing something?

Comment: Your question title implies that you _don't_ want to use tokens, but rather unique strings of some sort, for the user session.  But, the workflow in your question repeatedly mentions tokens.  What is your actual goal here?

Comment: well, maybe I'm wrong in terminology. In the context of my question, when I write "token" I imply "a randomly generated string" i.e. I use these terms interchangeably

Comment: My goal is to authenticate the user using my Auth.microservice

Comment: Right...but do you want to use session ID or token?  They are not the same things.

Comment: I use the session ID to authenticate the user that uses a web browser to access my app and I want to use token to protect Auth.microservice from unauthorized requests (cause this service also provides functionality to delete/create/edit/.. other users). So to prove to Auth.service that you're the same user who has signed in in my app, you send a token (stored in session) on each request. Without token  for example anyone can send curl requests to my auth.service and delete all users

Comment: Assuming the random string generation is using a cryptographically secure random function, and everything is done through SSL, I don't see any possible problem, though you might want to ask on https://security.stackexchange.com/